# Unable to get basic custom Magento payment module to work

Tags: magento, module, payment

I want to create a payment module which is basically identical to the Check/Money Order method, in that when you click the radio button to select it, a bit of information with instructions appears underneath.

I have created a module which works, but I can't get that info to appear underneath. When I enable it, I simply get a blank error page (with no message).

I have the following files inside my module folder:

- **Block/Form/Bacs.php**
- **Block/Info/Bacs.php**
- **etc/config.xml**
- **etc/system.xml**
- **Model/Method/Bacs.php**

And frontend-wise I have the following files:

- **payment/info/bacs.phtml**
- **payment/form/bacs.phtml**

I think the problem lies in my block php files because when I remove the links to them from my Model file the module works. Here's an overview of the files where I think the problem lies:

**Model/Method/Bacs.php**

```
class Creare_Bacs_Model_Method_Bacs extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
{

    protected $_code  = 'bacs';
    protected $_formBlockType = 'bacs/form_bacs';
    protected $_infoBlockType = 'bacs/info_bacs';

    public function assignData($data)
    {
        $details = array();

        if ($this->getInstructions()) {
            $details['instructions'] = $this->getInstructions();
        }
        if (!empty($details)) {
            $this->getInfoInstance()->setAdditionalData(serialize($details));
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function getInstructions()
    {
        return $this->getConfigData('instructions');
    }

}
```

**Block/Info/Bacs.php**

```
class Creare_Bacs_Block_Info_Bacs extends Mage_Payment_Block_Info
{

    protected $_instructions;

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('payment/info/bacs.phtml');
    }

    public function getInstructions()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_instructions)) {
            $this->_convertAdditionalData();
        }
        return $this->_instructions;
    }

    protected function _convertAdditionalData()
    {
        $details = @unserialize($this->getInfo()->getAdditionalData());
        if (is_array($details)) {
            $this->_instructions = isset($details['instructions']) ? (string) $details['instructions'] : '';
        } else {
            $this->_instructions = '';
        }
        return $this;
    }

}
```

**Block/Form/Bacs.php**

```
class Creare_Bacs_Block_Form_Bacs extends Mage_Payment_Block_Form
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('payment/form/bacs.phtml');
    }

}
```

Within my system.xml file I have this which brings out the instructions textarea in the picture below:

```
<instructions translate="label">
              <label>Instructions</label>
              <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
              <sort_order>2</sort_order>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</instructions>
```

[image]

Really not sure what I've done wrong. I don't want this first post to be too long so let me know if any more files are needed. I'm sure that the problem is within the block files I have provided.

Can anyone tell me if I have made an error in creating any of the files I have shown above?

Comment: paste in your config.xml as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm such a dummy. Forgot to register blocks in config.xml (you would have spotted it Anton S)

```
<blocks>
    <bacs>
       <class>Creare_Bacs_Block</class>
    </bacs>
</blocks>
```

Comment: Please mark your own answer as accepted, it is allowed and even suggested by stackoverflow rules.